# Eliminating the effect of locator in Mathematica when it is outside a range

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to limit the effect of locator, so when I click on the space but not between some required range, the locator does nothing. Right now it will be located at the nearest point of the range to the point that I have clicked. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using `Manipulate` which include this behaviour, e.g.

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, p}],
  PlotRange -> 2], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

One solution would be to use `DynamicModule` instead:

```
DynamicModule[{p = {1, 1}}, Deploy@Framed@
   Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, Dynamic[p]}],
     Locator[Dynamic[p]]}, PlotRange -> 2]]
```

Also related:

[What is the equivalent of a prototypical Manipulate in lower level functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4878/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-prototypical-manipulate-in-lower-level-functions)